# Why is LaTeX and TeX not supported in the TeX stackexchange?

Tags: support, formatting, request-for-information

For some inexplicable reason, the normal $ notation for LaTeX is not supported on SE (other than math). How can I otherwise use TeX and LaTeX on this SE site at least?

Comment: Why down-voting? The question is a natural one, as documented by the fact that it has already been answered (because asked many times before).